# How to use ipython kernel running in docker container from Jupyter Notebook running in host machne?

Tags: docker, jupyter

I want to use ipython kernel inside a docker container from Jupyter Notebook running in my host machine.

I know I can use the kernel by installing Jupyter into the container, but it is not I want to do.
That's because I'm using some extensions of Jupyter Notebook (e.g. vim), and I want to use them when I use the kernel inside docker container.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/tamera-lanham/ipython-kernel-docker), there you can find a complete example of how to run IPython inside Docker.